# Would it be appropriate to send your CV to a researcher who gave you their business card a few years ago?

Tags: phd, etiquette, job-search, professionalism

When I was presenting a paper at a conference ~3years ago, a researcher (who also happens to be a professor) gave me her business card after discussing with her after my presentation.

Now that I’m almost done with my PhD, I’d like to approach her to see if there could be a possible job opportunity at the research institute mentioned in her business card.

I was wondering if it would be appropriate to send her my CV along the email? Or if it would be seen as if I am “forcing” her to read it, especially that it has been almost 3 years since we met?

Would it be better to start with an introductory email first, and then send her the CV only if she asks me to?

I also thought about including a link to my LinkedIn account in my email signature, so that she can check my profile (if she wants to), without me explicitly sending my CV in the email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just a simple email asking if she has any opportunities and reminding her that you met at that conference.

Include the cv as an attachment and she can open it, or not, as she wishes.

Comment: yes that was the idea. The only doubt I had is if it is widely-accepted to include the CV in a first email, especially that it has been quite a long time since the first encounter.

Comment: Well, you can send 15 emails establishing a conversation before sending the cv or do what I suggest - up to you. What is widely accepted is dependent on the situation, some will only expect a cv when they ask, others will be happy to see it in the first email - whether they read it or not is another question.

Comment: This is the most reasonable answer. There is no harm in attaching a CV. Besides, how will the professor know if the positions are suitable for you without knowing your resume?

Comment: @Titus , I thought I'd send it in a 2nd (not 15th) email, if asked to do so. Note that I've attached my CV along spontaneous applications in the past (prior to starting my PhD). No one has complained about that. I thought that the current context is different since I haven't thought of this as a spontaneous application (i.e. with the email body resembling a full cover letter) but as an inquiry containing a few elements of a usual cover letter.  If sending the CV seems appropriate, I'll do it.

Comment: Or include a link to your online CV in your email signature. That way, it's not quite so in-your-face as an attachment, but the recipient can still review your CV if they want.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - yes.

I think that's a big part of what conferences are for.

Also don't overlook using Linked In as a means of starting the conversation.